# How do I count the items in a single column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe I have a column whose items are lists containing strings. There are three available strings but every list can contain zero or more of each of these strings.

My aim is to create three columns with the count of each string, either as an absolute number or percentage.

```
import pd
import collections

df[["C1", "C2", "C3"]] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.D).value_counts(), axis=1)
```

I used `df[["C1", "C2", "C3"]] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(collections.Counter(x.D)), axis=1)`, but I get the following error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: Sample data and desired output would make this much more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you're trying to do correctly,

Assuming the strings you are interested are in array `strings` and the data frame's column containing the string arrays is `D`, then this code should do the trick

```
strings=['C1','C2','C3']
output_df=pd.DataFrame([])
for s in strings:
    output_df[s]=input_df['D'].apply(lambda arr:len([item for item in arr if item==s]))
```

And if you want to append the new columns to the old data frame, simply use the same `DataFrame` for both input and output

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could easily solve this before you generate the dataframe. If you have three lists that each contain a variable number of your three strings. So how about this instead:

```
import pandas as pd

possible_strings = ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')
list_1 = ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
list_2 = ['C2']
list_3 = ['C3', 'C3']

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
list_of_series = []
for x in range(len(lists)):
    vals = []
    for s in possible_strings:
        vals.append(lists[x].count(s))
    list_of_series.append(pd.Series(vals))

df = pd.concat(list_of_series, axis=1)
```

This creates the data frame you seem to want.